# Python unknown number of commandline arguments in boto3

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, boto3

I am trying to add tags based on commandline arguments passed to python script something like below:

```
./snapshot-create.py --id abcd  --key1 Env --value1 Test
```

The script is like below:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.create_tags(
    Resources=[
        ID,
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'key1',
            'Value': 'value1'
        },
    ]
)
```

I want to use --key1 and --values as Tags as above but the problem is that there could be more than one tags that need to be added like:

```
./snapshot-create.py --id abcd  --key1 Env --value1 Test -key2 Loca --value2 US -key1 Size --value1 small ...
```

How would I use those key-values if their number of arguments is not fixed.

I don't mind using function or any other way than what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be loading a json string as a dictionary and iterating it when creating the tags.

For example, consider this invocation:

```
$ my_script.py --tags "{'tag1': 'value1', 'tag2': 'value2'}" --id i-1234567890 i-0987654321
```

and this code snippet:

```
import json
import boto3
import argparse

parser.add_argument('-t', '--tags', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-i', '--id', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
client = boto3.client('ec2')

def create_tags(key, value, resources, c):
    c.create_tags(
    Resources=
        resources,
    ,
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': key,
            'Value': value
        },
    ]
)

my_tags = json.loads(args.tags)  # {'tag1': 'value1', 'tag2': 'value2'}
resources = args.id  # ['i-1234567890', 'i-0987654321']
for k, v in my_tags.items():
    create_tags(k, v, resources, client)
```

This should cause instances `i-1234567890` & `i-0987654321` to be tagged with both tags `tag1` and `tag2` described in `--tags` above.

If you require a more dynamic interface for resources as well, consider adding it to the json as such:

```
{ 'instance_id': [{'tag_key': 'tag_value'} ... ] ... }
```

You can the take a single argument `--tags` which will contain a mapping of resources and tags, instead of the above example where resources is statically mapped to the tags.

Pretty sure there are better, more pythonic, solutions than this though - this is one viable solution.